# Is it possible to solve the heat equation with this boundary conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to solve the heat equation, $$\partial_{xx}^2 \theta(x,t) = \frac{1}{\kappa} \partial_t \theta(x,t),$$ for $x \in [0,L]$ and $t \in [0, \infty)$.

The boundary conditions that I have to use are as follows. At $x=0$, I'm going to use a square wave for the temperature, so $$\theta(0,t) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{4 \theta_0}{n \pi} \sin{\left( \frac{2n \pi}{\tau} t \right)}+ \theta_0', $$ where $\theta_0$ and $\theta_0'$ are two constant values for $\theta$. Initially, I'll suppose a constant value for $\theta$, that I'll write as $$\theta (x,0)=\theta_0', $$ to be consistent with the previous condition. Finally, for $x=L$, I'll assume that heat transfer is due to convection only, so $$ \left. \partial_x \theta(x,t) \right|_{x=L} = \frac{h}{\kappa} \left( \theta(L,t) - \theta_{a} \right), $$ where $h$, $\kappa$ and $\theta_a$ are constant values.

Is it possible to solve something like this? This is a theoretical model for a experience we studied in the lab.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to solve the heat equation for the boundary conditions and initial conditions you have in mind, but not the way you're thinking of doing it.

Comment: I thought this could be solved separating variables and imposing the boundary conditions, but after a few failed attempts to do that, I didn't know how to proceed.

Comment: Step 1:  Solve for the final steady state temperature profile.  What do you get?  (Also, in the equation for the boundary condition at x = L, shouldn't that be the thermal conductivity in the denominator, not the thermal diffusivity (assuming h is the heat transfer coefficient).  And shouldn't this boundary condition have a minus sign?

Comment: Using the minor changes I indicated in my previous comment, I get the following for the final steady state temperature profile:$$\theta_{SS}=\theta'+\frac{\beta(\theta_a-\theta')}{(1+\beta)}\frac{x}{L}$$where $\beta=\frac{hL}{k}$.  Is this what you get?